# How to know the length of an audio recording in Android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am using the following code to record audio:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  intent.setType("audio/*");
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select audio source"), CardList.ACTIVITY_RECDAUDIO);
```

When the result comes back I do the following:

```
  Uri u = intent.getData();
  String audioUri = u.getPath();
  InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(u));
```

I would like to know how long the recording is in seconds.  Is it possible to query this somehow?  If all else fails I can play the clip programatically and time it, but I would prefer a more direct method if possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is fast enough for you. But in case you don't know - you don't have to actually play it. It is enough to create `MediaPlayer` instance and set the path of the file and the call `getDuration()`.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(yourActivity, Uri.parse(path));
int duration = mp.getDuration();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this by using my input stream: is.available() on InputStream is gives me the length.