# Android audio recorder api

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am using the android audio recorder api. How do I get the duration of clip that was recorded.

Is there any built in method? I only see `setmaxtime()`; ?

Comment: @lxt:heck this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849502/how-to-know-the-length-of-an-audio-recording-in-android can i use that getduration().

Answer (score 0):

setmaxtime() is not actually method.
setMaxDuration() it actually set that how much time it will be recorded. if you set
setMaxDuration(-1), it will be recorded untill you stop or till your sdcard not finished.
if you set setMaxDuration(10 * 1000) (that is milisec) that means it will automatically stopped after 10 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this method in your Utils class as static and pass file path of recorded file.

Note: Here you will get duration in milliseconds.

Android gives class named as MediaMetadataRetriever to fetch all the details of any file type like size,width,height,duration,codec format,etc.

`

```
public static long getAudioDurationByFilePath(String aFilePath){
        long mMilliSeconds=0;
        try{
            MediaMetadataRetriever lMediaMetaDataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            lMediaMetaDataRetriever.setDataSource(aFilePath);
            String lDurationString = lMediaMetaDataRetriever.extractMetadata(
                    MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
            mMilliSeconds =  Long.parseLong(lDurationString);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.w("AudioUtils","SetDataSource ON NULL OBJECT REFERENCE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.w("AudioUtils","returning duration: "+mMilliSeconds);
        return mMilliSeconds;
    }
```

`